# Best practices for Hangfire on Azure

Tags: azure, hangfire

I am attempting to migrate an OnPrem solution to Azure. The application uses Hangfire fairly heavily. Hangfire is hosted in a windows service and is backed by SQL Server.

I prefer not to remove this dependency unless absolutely required. (alternatives being functions/webjobs.)

**Are there any guidelines/best practices for running Hangfire on Azure?**

Barring the differences in storage characteristics, is Hangfire expected to work exactly on azure as it does OnPrem?

On googling + scanning github issues & SO:

1. People do seem to be using Hangfire on Azure.
2. Could not find any best-practice/migration documents around this.

Thanks,
Partho

Answer (score 8):

If you use Hangfire, I highly recommend you use their **[`Azure Service Bus`](https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire.Azure.ServiceBusQueue)** package. Which switches the polling to Azure SB